# C# in javascript executes only once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I try to read the data from Azure Database code does so correctly on page load/refresh but then it repeats the very same data, even though I call a function to get a new one.

C# Code for fetching data.

```
public static class GetSensorData
{
public static List<Reading> GetTemperatureSensorData(int quantity)
    {
        decimal TemperatureCelcius;
        DateTime TimeOfAReading;
        string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rpiDB"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        List<Reading> TempTemperatureList = new List<Reading> { };

        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand GetTemperature = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + quantity + " * FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY time DESC;", Connection);

        Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter TempAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(GetTemperature);
        DataTable TempereatureSensorDataTable = new DataTable();
        TempAdapter.Fill(TempereatureSensorDataTable);

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            TemperatureCelcius = (decimal)TempereatureSensorDataTable.Rows[i][0];
            //gotta change the culture from within
            TemperatureCelcius = decimal.Parse(TemperatureCelcius.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeOfAReading = (DateTime)TempereatureSensorDataTable.Rows[i][1];
            TempTemperatureList.Add(new Reading(TemperatureCelcius, TimeOfAReading.ToString("HH/mm")));
        }

        Connection.Close();
        return TempTemperatureList;
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it in CSHTML

```
var updateData = function (oldData) {
            var labels = oldData["labels"];
            var dataSetA = oldData["datasets"][0]["data"];
            @{ 
                List<Reading> SingleReading = new List<Reading>(GetSensorData.GetTemperatureSensorData(1));
            }               
            var datetime = @SingleReading[0].TimeOfReading
            labels.push(String(datetime));
            labels.shift();
            var Temperature = @(SingleReading[0].TemperatureCelcius);
            dataSetA.push(Temperature / 100);
            dataSetA.shift();            
        };
setInterval(function () {
            updateData(data);
            myLineChart.data = data;
            myLineChart.update();
        }, 5000
        );
```

The function in setInterval is being executed every 5 seconds but with the data, I got on the page load.

Comment: Though setInterval is being executed every 5 sec, it doesn't execute GetSensorData.GetTemperatureSensorData(1) because it's a c# code. Javascript can't execute c# codes. You have to do an ajax call to server for new data, inside 'updateData' js function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, I've figured it out.

This is my CS code from HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetTemp(int quantity)
    {
        decimal TemperatureCelcius;
        DateTime TimeOfReading;
        string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rpiDB"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        List<Reading> TempTemperatureList = new List<Reading> { };

        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand GetTemperature = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP " + quantity + " * FROM tbl_temp ORDER BY time DESC;", Connection);

        Connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter TempAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(GetTemperature);
        DataTable TempereatureSensorDataTable = new DataTable();
        TempAdapter.Fill(TempereatureSensorDataTable);

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            TemperatureCelcius = (decimal)TempereatureSensorDataTable.Rows[i][0];            
            TimeOfReading = (DateTime)TempereatureSensorDataTable.Rows[i][1];
            TempTemperatureList.Add(new Reading(TemperatureCelcius, TimeOfReading.ToString("HH:mm")));
        }
        Connection.Close();

        return Json(TempTemperatureList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And Ajax:

```
setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Home/GetTemp',                 
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: { 'quantity': 1 },                   
                success: function (response) { 
                    var _Temperature =  response[0].TemperatureCelcius;
                    var _TimeOfReading = response[0].TimeOfReading;
                    console.log(_Temperature);
                    updateData(data, _Temperature, _TimeOfReading);
                    myLineChart.data = data;
                    myLineChart.update();
                },                   
                error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message ' + err); }
            });

        }, 5000
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web service in your C# project so that you can make AJAX calls to `GetTemperatureSensorData`. I recommend putting this into its own Web API project. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx

Next, you will need to create an AJAX call to the web service in your javascript code. To make this easier to do, I recommend using the jQuery library, specifically the `get` command: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/